# Follow-card html css

Tags: html, css

I made this followers Card design but am having a bit of problem when styling it, when I try to add `margin-right` to align the image to the right side of the container for some reason it doesn't align to the right, It aligns it more to the left and it stretches the container, it also grabs the text even though they're both in separate containers, same for the button. And for some reason instead of using padding on the `follow__content`, I instead used gave a width but for some reason the image get left out.

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.2%;
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.follow__container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.follow__content {
  background-color: rgba(206, 194, 178, 0.836);
  line-height: 1.2;
  padding: 2rem 10rem;
}

.img__container {
  width: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

.img__container img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  border-radius: 5rem;
}

.follow__desc {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 0 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.99rem;
}

.follow__btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  left: 8rem;
  position: relative;
  top: -1.6rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.follow__btn a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  background-color: #222095;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="follow__container">
  <div class="follow__content">

    <div class="img__container">
      <img src="cybercybrog.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="follow__desc">
      <h2>Mr Cyborg</h2>
      <p>#CyberCity</p>
      <p>Most Popular</p>
    </div>

    <div class="follow__btn">
      <a href="#">Follow</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understant what you are trying to do. Do you want to set the image on the right of the card?

Comment: yea but it instead move the image and the text to the right even though there both in separate divs

Comment: Can you upload an image of how should it look like?

Comment: it should be there now

Comment: I don't see the difference between the image and the code result. In case you missunderstood, I was asking you to upload an image of the result that you want, making it on paint or wherever, to see the items position.

Comment: well thats the the results i want but

Comment: ok so from the code I made follow__content: paddding: 1.4rem 10rem to add some space but i then when to separate the image from the text it also aligns the text along with the image even though I only wanted the image to align the the right.

Comment: yea I think i get it now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this is your desired output.I used the `padding property` in the `follow__content` class and changed its' values by giving all the sides padding like this. Since you had given padding only for two sides it was applied incorrectly.

```
.follow__content {
  background-color: rgba(206, 194, 178, 0.836);
  line-height: 1.2;
  padding: 10px 100px 10px 10px;  
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.2%;
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.follow__container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.follow__content {
  background-color: rgba(206, 194, 178, 0.836);
  line-height: 1.2;
  padding: 20px 100px 20px 10px;  
}

.img__container {
  width: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

.img__container img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  border-radius: 5rem;
}

.follow__desc {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 0 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.99rem;
}

.follow__btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  left: 8rem;
  position: relative;
  top: -1.6rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.follow__btn a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  background-color: #222095;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="follow__container">
  <div class="follow__content">
    <div class="img__container">
      <img src="https://www.slashfilm.com/img/gallery/joss-whedon-says-he-cut-cyborgs-justice-league-storyline-because-ray-fisher-is-a-bad-actor/l-intro-1642457019.jpg" alt="Profile Image">
    </div>
    <div class="follow__desc">
      <h2>Mr Cyborg</h2>
      <p>#CyberCity</p>
      <p>Most Popular</p>
    </div>
    <div class="follow__btn">
      <a href="#">Follow</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wait i have one more problem, this time its for the button before i tried moving to the left using margin-left it work but i wanted to move it to the edge but it ending up stretching the content

Comment: Can you update the error in the question again. So that I can help. @Kai